Examples for strictly unital $A_\infty$ spaces
I would like to understand the classical notion of an $A_\infty$ space. Clearly, the idea of such spaces comes from ways of iterated bracketings of loops. However, in Stasheff's original definition, the multiplication has to be unital. Therefore, the loop space of a pointed space does not immediately come with the structure of an $A_\infty$ space. Is there some construction that turns a loop space into an $A_\infty$ space?
For instance, can the standard way of making an $H$-space unital (i. e. by attaching an interval at the identity) be applied on a loop space in order to achieve this?
Concretely, in degree 3, this would amount to constructing a family of three-multiplications
$$m_3: I \times (\Omega X \cup_{\{1\}}[0,1])^3 \to \Omega X \cup_{\{1\}}[0,1]$$
satisfying compatibility with the multiplication $m_2$.
I know that there is the strictly unital Moore loop space, but that does not quite satisfy me since it seems to miss the whole point of the associahedra, as it is also strictly associative.
Is this done somewhere?
